# python reports missing parameter

Tags: python, object, self

I have a function in an object which requires 5 params. I create an instance of that object and run the function, define(param1,2,3,4,5) and it gives me a response of missing the fifth parameter.

Here is part of my code:

```
    class KeyProperties:   #Object
path = None
keytype = None
image = None
name = None
keyid = None
occupied = None

def define(self, name, path, image, keytype, keyid): #The function that is used
    self.path = path
    self.keytype = keytype
    self.image = image
    self.name = name
    self.keyid = keyid
    self.occupied = True
```

The code when I run define():

```
    key = KeyProperties
    key.define(param1,param2,param3,param4,param5)
```

and it gives out this error

> TypeError: define() missing 1 required positional argument: 'keyid'

Answer (score 8):

Your current `key` is not an instance of `KeyProperties` but the class itself. Hence `define` will require 6 parameters (which includes `self`):

To fix this, instantiate the class:

```
key = KeyProperties()
#                  ^^
```

The first argument to an instance method is the instance itself (usually written as `self`). Instantiating the class automatically passes `self` for you, and then `define` can now take 5 parameters as you intend.